# How do you solve the following PDE $\nabla_x y(x) \cdot y(x) = f(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How do you solve PDEs of the form  $\nabla_x y(x) \cdot y(x) = f(x)$?

Here, $y:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\nabla_x y(x)$ is the gradient of $y(x)$ w.r.t $x$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a continuous function.

Comment: **Hint:** Your equation can be written as $$\vec{\nabla}\left(y^{2}\right)=2f$$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is equivalent to
$$
∇_x(y(x)^2)=2f(x)
$$
and you need the compatibility or integrability conditions $\text{rot} f=0$, that is,
$$
\frac{\partial f_i}{x_j}-\frac{\partial f_j}{x_i}=0\ \ \forall\, i<j
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is

$$\vec{\nabla}\left(y^{2}\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)\right)=2\boldsymbol{f}\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)$$

in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. Now lets assume that

$$\oint_{\gamma}\boldsymbol{f}\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)\cdot{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}=0$$

for every closed curve $\gamma\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m}$. Let $\boldsymbol{x}_{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$. For every $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ the line $\left[\boldsymbol{x}_{0},\boldsymbol{x}\right]\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m}$, so the solution is given by

$$y^{2}\left(x\right)=2\int_{\left[\boldsymbol{x}_{0},\boldsymbol{x}\right]}\boldsymbol{f}\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)\cdot{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}$$